# Is there any 3-simplex in this figure?

Tags: general-topology, simplex

I have a simple question. Is it possible to construct a 3-simplex (a, b, c, d) in the following figure?

My guess was that as we can generate an edge (a, c) by a linear combination of (a, d) and (a, b), there is no 3-simplex in this figure. It's rather two 2-simplices?

[image]

> ======= Edit

### Def: n-simplex

Let $\{p_0, \dots, p_n \}$ be a geometrically independent set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The n-simplex $\sigma$ spanned by the points $p_i$ to be the set of all points $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ of the form; $x = \sum^n_{i=0} t_i p_i$ where $\sum^n_{i=0} t_i = 1$ with $t_i$ being non-negative.

Comment: It really depends what you mean. Is this a combinatorial 3-simplex? No, rather a simplicial complex of two 2-simplices. Is it the standard geometric 3-simplex? No. Can this be seen as a degenerate 3-simplex or projection of a standard 3-simplex? Yes.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, it makes sense. thanks. it's a complex of two 2-simplices. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for your answer. Could you expand on why we need an extra edge connecting (b, d) to make a 3-simplex of (a, b, c, d)?
I added the definition that I have!

Comment: I don't know what "geometrically independent" means in your definition. If it is affinely independent then you need to be at least in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to have a 3-simplex. But note that your definition does not include any "edges" or other "faces". Your simplex is just some set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (basically a convex hull of points). Then there is a question of how to interpret various drawings according to your definition.

Comment: There is no way to construct $m$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $m>n$. What you have here is a simplicial complex, not a single simplex.